# Returning a pointer by reference

Tags: c++

I have seen some C++ that looks like this:

```
const Foo*& ptr = GetPointerToFoo();
```

Which seems to do the same job as:

```
const Foo* ptr = GetPointerToFoo();
```

Or even:

```
Foo* ptr = GetPointerToFoo();
```

What is the use of the `&` in the first example? Does it pass the value returned by `GetPointerToFoo()` by reference? What would be the use of this? Is it just to make it run faster so that this pointer does not need to be copied? If so, it seems rather a complicated implementation for a very small increase in speed... Or are there other reasons to use the `&` here?

Comment: It is the same as returning *anything* by reference.

Comment: In this case, it's just pointless (no pun intended).

Comment: @nos You cannot possibly know what.

Comment: If this compiles: `const Foo*& ptr = GetPointerToFoo();`, then this should not: `Foo* ptr = GetPointerToFoo();` (although it might be allowed in MSVC due to the extension to allow non-const references to bind to temporaries)

Comment: On further testing, it shouldn't work with MSVC either, since the extension doesn't seem to apply to scalar types (like pointers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `const Foo*& ptr`: The reference makes the pointer itself mutable. The
  caller can modify the internal pointer (e.g. to nullptr), but not the internal content (which is probably useless).
- `const Foo* ptr`: A pointer to immutable content. The caller can
  not modify the internal pointer.
- `Foo* ptr`: A pointer to mutable content. The caller can modify the
  internal content, but not the internal pointer.

Note: Returning a pointer by reference is another indirection and makes the code not faster.

Note: I assume three distinct `GetPointerToFoo()` in the question.

Comment: Not _necessarily_ useless. Perhaps you want to change an internal strategy object, which for some reason shouldn't change its state in that context.